# Sum array inside array elements and bind it in html inside an ngFor loop div in angular8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

*)Please check out this 2 images in this i have a stock-shift array it's length is 2 and inside every
array i have another array, in the inside array i have to sum the elements of the quantity

*)check my html code and ts file and help me with the solution

*)Check the third image Ui there I need to bind sum value before the quantities like that for every
tile (box) i need to get different value but it is updating last value in all tiles (boxes)

```
   html
====
        <div *ngFor="let data of dataSource; let i = index;">
          <!-- Stockshift card -->
          <mat-card *ngIf="type === 'shift'" class="mb-3 card" (click)="addParams(data,data?.invoiceNumber,5, i)">
            <mat-card-content class="p-2" fxLayout="column">
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                <div><span [ngClass]="{'text-success' : data?.isSyncSuccess, 'text-danger' : data?.isSyncFailed, 'text-warning': (!data?.isSyncFailed && !data.isSyncSuccess)}"><b>#{{ data?.invoiceNumber }}</b></span></div>
                <div><span [ngClass]="{'text-success' : data?.isSyncSuccess, 'text-danger' : data?.isSyncFailed, 'text-warning': (!data?.isSyncFailed && !data.isSyncSuccess)}"><b>{{ data?.entryDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</b></span></div>
              </div>
              <span class="text-dark pt-2 card-content">
                <span>{{(data?.type === 'TO') ? 'Sent' : 'Received'}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="data && data?.productList[0]?.quantity < 1"> product <span class="text-primary">({{data?.productList[0]?.quantity}} Quantity)</span> {{(data?.type === 'TO') ? 'to' : 'from'}} </span>
                <span *ngIf="data && data?.productList[0]?.quantity > 1"> products <span class="text-primary">({{totalProductList}} Quantities)</span> {{(data?.type === 'TO') ? 'to' : 'from'}} </span>
                <span class="text-primary"> {{ data?.shiftGodown?.outletName }} </span>
              </span>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
</div>


 
Ts file
======
     get totalProductList() {
        let quantity: number;
        this.transactionData.stockShift.forEach(stock => {
          quantity = stock.productList.reduce((stock, list) => {
            return stock + list.quantity;
            }, 0)
          });
          return quantity;
      }
```

[image: Pic 1] [image: pic 2] [image: pic 3]

Answer (score 0):

**1 solution** - if you want to use getter `totalProductList` you can create a component for your box and in this case getter will work as expected.

**stock.component.ts** for example

```
get totalProductList() {
       return this.stock.productList.reduce((stock, list) => {
           return stock + list.quantity;
            }, 0)
          });
    }
```

**2 solution (BAD, cause call function in template)** - you need to transform you getter to function and pass one box element to work correctly

**ts**

```
getTotalProductList(stock) {
   return stock.productList.reduce((stock, list) => {
       return stock + list.quantity;
        }, 0)
      });
}
```

**html**

```
<span class="text-primary">({{getTotalProductList(data)}} Quantities)</span>
```

**3 solution** - also transform you getter to function and call it for each element when you receive data and save to element property (stock .quantitiesSum for example, and use in html `{{stock .quantitiesSum}}`)

**p.s.**
I think you should compare productList.length instead productList[0].quantity here

```
<span *ngIf="data && data?.productList[0]?.quantity < 1">
```

**to**

```
<span *ngIf="data && data?.productList.length < 2">
```